# Why is this overloaded std::function parameter ambiguous?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have the below code, where a class is trying to take one of two std::function signatures through its constructor. I'm able to get the signature that has the double parameter to compile, but the parameter-less signature fails to compile, saying the call is ambiguous.

```
#include <functional>

class Foo
{
public:
  void baz(double value) {
  }
};

class Bar
{
public:
  void baz() {
  }  
};

class Overloader {
public:
    Overloader(std::function<void(double)> inFuncWithArg)
    : funcWithArg(inFuncWithArg)
    {
    }
    
    Overloader(std::function<void(void)> inFuncNoArg)
    : funcNoArg(inFuncNoArg)
    {
    }
    
private:
    std::function<void(double)> funcWithArg;
    std::function<void(void)> funcNoArg;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    
    // Compiles
    Overloader overloader1(std::bind(static_cast<void(Foo::*)(double)>(&Foo::baz)
            , &foo, std::placeholders::_1));
            
    // Fails to compile - "call of overloaded ‘Overloader(std::_Bind_helper::type)’ is ambiguous"
    Overloader overloader2(std::bind(static_cast<void(Bar::*)(void)>(&Bar::baz)
            , &bar));

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing that's causing this to fail? Also, are there any less-verbose ways to do this?

Here's the full error output

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:51:20: error: call of overloaded ‘Overloader(std::_Bind_helper::type)’ is ambiguous
             , &bar));
                    ^
main.cpp:32:5: note: candidate: Overloader::Overloader(std::function)
     Overloader(std::function<void(void)> inFuncNoArg)
     ^~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:27:5: note: candidate: Overloader::Overloader(std::function)
     Overloader(std::function<void(double)> inFuncWithArg)
     ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Could you kindly post the full error message verbatim from the compiler, including all "required from here" and any other messages? Why are you using these static casts?

Comment: Return of `std::bind` (as lambda) are not `std::function`.

Comment: Added the full output. The static casts were necessary for disambiguating the first signature, I assumed they would be the right approach for the 2nd as well.

Comment: The static cast may have been needed in an earlier version of the code, but in the code in the question neither one is needed.

Comment: Ah, understood, the behavior is the same without the static casts. The problem remains though, compilation failure due to the ambiguous parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is more about `std::bind` than `std::function`.

The result of the expression

```
std::bind(&Foo::baz, &foo, std::placeholders::_1)
```

is invocable with one *or more* arguments, where the first argument is convertible to double.

The result of the expression

```
std::bind(&Bar::baz, &bar)
```

is invocable with zero *or more* arguments, with no restrictions.

The first expression can thus only initialize `std::function<void(double)>`, but the second expression can initialize either `std::function<void(double)>` or `std::function<void(void)>` and is ambiguous.

Genuinely, do not use `std::bind`. You can use `std::bind_front` if you have it. Alternatively, use a lambda.

`std::bind_front`:

```
std::bind_front(&Foo::baz, &foo)
std::bind_front(&Bar::baz, &bar)
```

lambda:

```
[&foo](double) { foo.baz(value); }
[&bar] { bar.baz(); }
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you add an example of how to do this with a lambda?

Comment: Added examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lambda:

```
auto overloader1 = [&foo](double value) { foo.baz(value); };
auto overloader2 = [&bar]() { bar.baz(); }
```